# Host network access from linked container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've following `coder-compose` configuration:

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        links:
            - tomcat1:tomcat1
            - tomcat2:tomcat2
            - tomcat3:tomcat3
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    tomcat1:
        build: ./tomcat
        ports:
            - "8080"

    tomcat2:
        build: ./tomcat
        ports:
            - "8080"

    tomcat3:
        build: ./tomcat
        ports:
            - "8080"
```

So, the question is, how to get access to the host network from the linked container(s):`tomcat1`, `tomcat2`, `tomcat3`. Here is the diagram:

[image]

**Update**
Seems, my diagram doesn't help much. Nginx is a load balancer, Tomcat 1-3 are application nodes. Deployed web. app needs to get access to internet resource.

Comment: you mean to expose port `8080` to be access from the internet ?

Comment: no, I mean to get access to the internet from web application deployed on tomcat server.

Comment: it has already get access to the internet from tomcat containers.

Comment: You right, my fault. It was network configuration issue. The question is closed.

Comment: There has been a recent update (see my edited answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Internet access is by default active on all containers (in bridge mode). All you need to check is if the http(s)_proxy variables are set if you are behind a proxy.

If your question if how to access docker host from a container (and not the reverse: access a container from the local docker host), then you would need to inspect the routing table of a container: see "[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/6309)"

```
export DOCKER_HOST_IP=$(route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $2}')
```

There is a recent (June 2016) effort to add a  adding a dockerhost as an entry in `/etc/hosts` of all running containers: [issue 23177](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23177).
Update March 2020: this issue has been closed, and redirect to [PR 40007](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40007): "Support host.docker.internal in dockerd on Linux"

> This PR allows containers to connect to Linux hosts by appending a special string "`host-gateway`" to `--add-host` e.g. "`--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway`" which adds `host.docker.internal` DNS entry in `/etc/hosts` and maps it to `host-gateway-ip`
>
> This PR also add a daemon flag call `host-gateway-ip` which defaults to
>   the default bridge IP
>
> Docker Desktop will need to set this field to the Host Proxy IP so DNS requests for host.docker.internal can be routed to VPNkit
>
> This will be in Docker for Linux (and Docker Desktop, which runs the Linux daemon, although inside a lightweight VM).
>
> Difference between this and the current implementation on Docker Desktop is that;
>
> - the current Docker Desktop implementation is in a part of the code-base that's proprietary (i.e., part of how Docker Desktop is configured internally)
>     this code could be used by the Docker Desktop team in future as well (to be discussed)
> - this PR does not set up the "magic" `host.docker.internal` automatically on every container, but it can be used to run a container that needs this host by adding docker run `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway`
> - (to be discussed); setting that "magic" domain automatically on containers that are started could be implemented by adding an option for this in the `~/.docker/config.json` CLI configuration file.